# Dynamic row thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want to create dynamic adding and removing list rows in Thymeleaf and Spring Boot. 
I don't know how to use thymeleaf in dynamic rows, but i am trying to do it
So this is my code:

```
public class Form{
    private List<Obj> list = new ArrayList<>();
//...
}


public class Obj{
   private String a;
}
```

Controller:

```
 @GetMapping("/form")
    public String form(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("form", new Form());
        return "/form";
    }
```

HTML:

```
[...]
<form class="form-horizontal row-border" action="#" th:action="@{/form}" th:object="${form}" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
                <label class="col-md-2 control-label">...</label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <table id="myTable" class=" table order-list">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>String</td>

                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr th:each="row:${list}">
                            <td class="col-sm-1">
                                1
                            </td>
                            <td class="col-sm-3">
                                <input th:field="*{list[__${row.index}__].a}" type="text" name="xyz"  class="form-control"/>
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="5" style="text-align: left;">
                                <input type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block " id="addrow" value="Add row" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>                   
</form>

[...]
```

but i don't know how to get send data from form to controller

Answer (score 1):

The controller recieves your data based on the input names. `th:field` sets your input name in the proper way so the controller will recieve it.

Sadly, if you add a new row in the client, **where thymeleaf doesn't exist anymore**, you have to set the proper name manually. You can look up for which name to set in your new row inputs with a js function like this (or any other way):

```
var nextRow = 0;

while($("input[name='list[" + nextRow + "].a']").length){
    nextRow ++;
}
```

nextRow will have the next free row, just use it to build a name in the fashion of the ones thymeleaf generates and set it as your new input's name.

Comment: I don't fully understand, can you write an example?